# Quickbook : Auto generating invoice number on Import

Tags: import, quickbooks, iif

We have built an application that exports a Quickbooks-format IIF file for invoicing. The import into Quickbooks works great - no errors, puts the line items in fine, etc. 
However, it doesn't put anything in for the Invoice Number (when you look at an invoices the import generated, the field is blank). Granted, we've left the DOCNUM field
blank, but shouldn't Quickbooks auto-increment the Invoice Number?

So, is there a way to specify Quickbooks to auto-increment imported invoices, either in the IIF file, a setting in Quickbooks, or some kind of "Generate Invoice Numbers" function in Quickbooks itself for previously imported invoices?

Any help MUCH appreciated!!

Answer (score -1):

> We have built an application that exports a Quickbooks-format IIF file for invoicing.

You built an application which uses a file format which has been deprecated for about 10 years. :-(

> Granted, we've left the DOCNUM field blank, but shouldn't Quickbooks auto-increment the Invoice Number?

Unfortunately, this isn't the way IIF works. Using IIF, you'll have to specify a number.

Did I mention you shouldn't be using IIFs?

> So, is there a way to specify Quickbooks to auto-increment imported invoices, either in the IIF file, a setting in Quickbooks, or some kind of "Generate Invoice Numbers" function in Quickbooks itself for previously imported invoices?

Yes... but not using IIFs.

You should be using the QuickBooks SDK:

- https://developer.intuit.com/us#QuickBooksDesktopSDK

If you indicate what programming language you're using, we can probably provide a lot more detail about the correct way to go about this task.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Am using java programming language